# Adding Growth Rates in Excel Power Pivot

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, calculation

I have been trying to find a way to add a calculation to my Power Pivot table in order to calculate the weekly growth rates. The table looks like this:[image]

What I would like to achieve, is to have in the last column a calculation which, in principle, looks something like this: Week17 (latest week in the chart) / week 16 (previous week) -1 (shown in percentage).

Mind that the weeks can change (there is a filter added to the chart where the user can choose to see for example just the weeks in February) so I would still need to always measure latest week/previous week -1

I truly appreciate any help! Thank you everyone!

Comment: One way to do this is in "pieces". For starters, you need a Calendar/Dates table to lump the days into weeks. And then you need a weeknumber from whatever your "day one" is - and it goes in your Calendar table. Ferrari & Russo show how to do it here: https://www.daxpatterns.com/week-related-calculations/
Then once you have a PreviousWeek measure, it's just DIVIDE([Measure] - [Previous Week Measure], [Previous Week Measure],BLANK()) to get the percentage change.

Comment: Hi @Pieter and thank you for taking the time to help with this issue! I think that unfortunately I forgot to post some important info which could make everything easier, sorry for that! In the dataset I am working with I already have a column with the date, one with the week number, weekday, and year. How could I pack this directly into a formula? 
Could there also be a way to only compare same periods? for example, 1 week mon-wed vs. last week mon-wed? 
Thank you sosos much for you help again!!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need a calendar/date table for this. Then you can do something like to get the Previous Week value:
Previous Week Total =
CALCULATE (
SUM ( Table[Amount] ),
FILTER (
ALL ( Table ),
Table[Year] = MAX ( Table[Year] )
&& Table[WeekNumber]
= MAX ( Table[WeekNumber] ) - 1
)
)
And then once you have that, you can get the current week from the current evaluation context, and then subtract. (So you'd do a Sum in the measure, then subtract the previous week).